# How to make a voice calling web app using Nexmo services?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vonage

I have been trying to make an asp.net web application which has the ability to call people on their cellphones etc. I have to use Nexmo API for the calling purpose. Currently, I have implemented samples available on its website for eg. https://github.com/nexmo-community/nexmo-dotnet-quickstart/blob/ASPNET/NexmoDotNetQuickStarts/Controllers/VoiceController.cs

But none of the samples show how to make a call from a browser to lets say a cell phone number. I might be following the wrong links here. Any help will be greatly appreciated here. Edit: Below is the sample I have tried.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("voice/event")]
public string Event([FromBody] dynamic type)
{
    return "Event received";
}

[HttpPost]
[Route("voice/call")]
public string MakeCall([FromUri] string to)
{
    var TO_NUMBER = to;
    var NEXMO_NUMBER = "MyNexmoNumber";

    var results = Client.Call.Do(new Call.CallCommand
    {
        to = new[]
        {
            new Call.Endpoint {
                type = "phone",
                number = TO_NUMBER
            }
        },
        from = new Call.Endpoint
        {
            type = "phone",
            number = NEXMO_NUMBER
        },
        answer_url = new[]
        {
            "https://developer.nexmo.com/ncco/tts.json"
        }
    });

    var callUUID = results.uuid;

    return callUUID;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The example give is with respect to ASP.NET MVC. `MakeCall` method in the controller accepts parameter `to` from the the UI. And makes call to that number. Can you share whatever code you have tried and tell what issue you are facing?

Comment: I have supplied the sample above. The thing is I want to make a call from the browser, like i should be able to talk from the browser to the person on the cell phone.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Nexmo in-app voice product if you want to make voice calls from browser. 
[Here's a link on how to use this](https://www.nexmo.com/blog/2018/08/21/phone-call-web-browser-nexmo-in-app-voice-vue-js-dr/)  , it's in vue.js but hopefully it will give you a good idea on the approach to follow.

Comment: Thanks@Rabeb. Just wanted to say I have seen your posts on the Nexmo website too. Also, is this link going to useful for the said use case: 
https://developer.nexmo.com/stitch/in-app-voice/guides/outbound-pstn

Comment: Yes that's going to be useful :)

Comment: Thanks that did work some what, I am still unable to make call using the Vue.js sample. Something to do with "reason: {text: "Call refused, number has not been found, ["Hangup-Cause"=UNALLOCATED_NUMBER]", code: "REMOTE_NOT_FOUND", sip_code: 404}"

Comment: It looks like an error related to the phone number. Is the the phone number to connect to in E.164 format? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.164

Comment: So, the sample was using a ready made vue component which was adding a "+" in front of the number. Removing that plus sign solved the issue.